# Accessing elements of an array defined in a class (C++)

Tags: c++, class, arrays

Assume that int array arrayName is a member of class className, How can I access its element in my main program??  className.arrayName[0] doesn't seem to work

Comment: Could you add some code to the question?

Comment: did you try objectofclassName.arrayName[0]?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `arrayName` is static inside class `className`, then you can access it like that:

```
//Declaration
class className{
public: 
  static int arrayName[5];
};

//Access
className::arrayName[index];
```

If it is not static, you must create an instance of your class first.

```
//Declaration
class className{
public: 
  int arrayName[5];
};

//Access
className a;
a.arrayName[index];
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be `objectName.arrayName[index]`, where `objectName` is an instance of your class.
Don't forget to declare your `arrayName` public.

(Assuming that your `arrayName` is not static.)